# C++ constexpr function not recognized as such in template

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I get `'sizeof (((A*)0)->A::m_i)' is not a constant expression` error message in gcc(v4.9.2) with the following code.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

---

Header File: a.h

```
struct A {
    int m_i;

    static constexpr 
    size_t size() { return sizeof(m_i); } // no error if returns sizeof(decltype(m_i))
};
```

Header File: b.h

```
#include "a.h"

template<typename T>    
struct B {
    static constexpr size_t size_of_A = A::size();
};
```

Source File: main.cpp

```
#include "b.h" // <-- Triggers the error(all else the same)

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

---

The error disappears with any of these modifications:

- the `#include` directive in `main.cpp` is removed
- `struct B` is changed into a non-template
- `A::size()` is modified as `return sizeof(decltype(m_i));`

P.S. In response to some comments received regarding the post, please note that:

a) The code has to be laid out in different files **as indicated** to reproduce the error.

b) The code does **not** contain the expression `((A*)0)->A::m_i` anywhere.

Comment: The code you actually show doesn't contain any `((A*)0)->A::m_i`. You don't present a proper [mcve], please address that.

Comment: No problem here: https://ideone.com/nX4lri

Comment: A [mcve] is not a link to some external web site that can stop working at any time, rendering this question meaningless. You must provide a [mcve] in your question itself, ***as plain text***.

Comment: @StoryTeller : I understand why you would say that but the code I provided reproduces the error I describe exactly as it is. It does not contain the expression `((A*)0)->A::m_i`.

Comment: @Kemal - It doesn't, not by itself. And Killzone Kid demonstrates that.

Comment: @KillzoneKid : I don't get any errors when the entire code is in one source file. That is why I indicated the different header and source files.

Comment: @StoryTeller : I reproduce the error when the code is laid out in files as I have indicated. I have edited the OP to stress that point.

Comment: @Kemal your error clearly states you have a piece of code that looks like this `sizeof (((A*)0)->A::m_i)`. And according to you, it appears out of nowhere when you take your code and put it in different files. Hmm, this is a tough one, some kind of witchcraft could be involved.

Comment: Or more likely still, you are compiling a stale version of some file, that contains that illegal construct.

Comment: @StoryTeller : I am afraid that is not the case. I get the same error in clean builds.

Comment: @KillzoneKid : Just to be clear: The code that reproduces the error does **not** have the expression `sizeof (((A*)0)->A::m_i)`. It appears in the error code I get from the compiler.

Comment: Alright. What version of GCC are you using?

Comment: @StoryTeller : Note that KillZone Kid compiled the entire code in a single file. I don't get the error that way either. I get it when the code is laid out as indicated in OP.

Comment: @StoryTeller : I use gcc version 4.9.2. Mingm32, if it makes a difference. I am not knowledgeable on these matters.

Comment: @Kemal Told you, black magic

Comment: I'm not dense, thank you. And I was willing to humor this being a compiler error. So see if updating GCC helps, because we can't tell you if **your system** has a configuration problem.

Comment: @StoryTeller : I might have overstated some points in my comments. I meant no disrespect. That being said, OP stands well as a fine MCVE. For those who are able to reproduce the error, off course.

Comment: Other includes? Killzone Kid include `iostream`but I don't see standard includes in you code. Without `iostream` or other standard headers, `size_t` (in `size_t size()` and in `size_t size_of_A`) should give error.

Comment: @max66 : It compiles fine as it is except for the error mentioned. You can include `iostream` if you like. I still get the same error.

Comment: cannot reproduce: without `#include <iostream>` I get errors from `std::size_t` unrecognized; including `iostream` your code compile with both g++ (but my g++ is newer: 6.3.0) and clang++. I suspect a bug in g++ 4.9.2. Which compiler flags do you use?

Comment: @max66 : Compiler flags used:  -Wall -std=c++11 -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 (for debug) -Wall -fexceptions -O2 -std=c++11 (for release)

Comment: @max66 : BTW, are you compiling the code in a single source file, or in 3 different files as indicated in OP? It does compile fine otherwise.

Comment: I'm compiling in three files, a.h b.h and main.cpp; exactly as in you example; I'll try with your exactly compiler flags; you get the error from both debug and release?

Comment: No errors from both debug and release flags sets. But I repeat: I have g++ 6.3.0. I suspect a bug in you particular version.

Comment: @max66 : Yes, I do get errors in both compilations. Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to arise from gcc version. Updating to 5.1.0 solves the issue.